# Drag drop selection plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, drag-and-drop

I'm using [this](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drop/demo/selection) plugin to select text on a website.

My code looks like this so far:

```
jQuery(function($){
            $( document )
            .drag("start",function( ev, dd ){
                return $('<div class="selection" />')
                .css('opacity', .65 )
                .appendTo( document.body );
            })
            .drag(function( ev, dd ){
                $( dd.proxy ).css({
                    top: Math.min( ev.pageY, dd.startY ),
                    left: Math.min( ev.pageX, dd.startX ),
                    height: Math.abs( ev.pageY - dd.startY ),
                    width: Math.abs( ev.pageX - dd.startX )
                });
            })
            .drag("end",function( ev, dd ){
                $( dd.proxy ).remove();
            });
            $('article p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, ul')
            .drop(function( ev, dd ){
                $(this).wrap('<div />')
            })
            $.drop({ multi: true });    
        });
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to wrap all the selected elements in on `<div>`. Right now it's wrapping each element into separate div's.
Here's the code fragment that is responsible for this:

```
.drop(function( ev, dd ){
                $(this).wrap('<div />')
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the function [wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) is what you're looking for, instead of wrap.